# Extract first three octet from IP address

Tags: regex, ip-address

I need to extract first three octet from a IP address(class C) and I can do it by splitting on `"//."`. But is there a way to do it using REGEX.

Input : `192.168.1.1` Output : `192.168.1`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
/^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}/
```

Use match and it is done..

Answer (score 0):

More precisely for Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3}).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("127.0.2.13");
if (m.matches()) {
    String s0 = m.group(1);   // contains "127"
    String s1 = m.group(2);   // contains "0"
    String s2 = m.group(3);   // contains "2"
    System.out.println("s0 + "." + s1 + "." + s2);
}
```

This slightly more simple pattern also works:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3}).*");
```

Really good regex tutorial [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).